# Calculation of Days between two dates Salesforce Giving diffrent result in Dev Console and diffrent in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, date, datetime, developer-console

I am using simple formula to calculate days between two dates.How while running in Trigger it is giving me different numbers.
Devconsole:

`Date Account_Opened_Date = Date.valueOf('2016-09-27');
 Date Submit_Time_Stamp = Date.valueOf('2016-06-29');
 system.debug(Submit_Time_Stamp.daysBetween(Account_Opened_Date) + 1);`

Result = 91 days

Trigger (putting Same date)

`Date startDate = Date.valueOf(newAccount.Submit_Time_Stamp__c);
  Date dueDate = newAccount.Account_Opened_Date__c;
  Integer noofDays = startDate.daysBetween(dueDate) + 1;`

Result= 90 days

Comment: Is "Submit Time Stamp" a date-time?

Comment: Yes @sfdcfox datetime field